# Como carregar img em jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Olá pessoal gostaria de saber como carregar imagem dentro de um append();

segue o link

```
append("<tr><td>"+value.codigo+"</td><td>"+value.nome+"</td><td>CARREGAR IMAGEM AQui</td><tr>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas coloque dentro do src de uma img:

```js
var linkImagem = 'http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-640-480-4.jpg';
$("body").append(" <img src=" + linkImagem + " alt='Exemplo'> ");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `jQuery(".lists-data").append("<tr><td>"+value.codigo+"</td><td>"+value.nome+"</td><td><img src="img/edit.png" class="btn-action"></td><tr>");`

Comment: tentei o codigo acima e nao funcinou

Comment: @VictorMorais seu problema e de sintax, veja os atributos src e classe com aspas duplas, troque por aspas simples que ira resolver

Answer (score 1):

Para criar um elemento e inserí-lo com jQuery podes fazer assim:

```
jQuery('<img />', {
    src: "img/edit.png"
}).appendTo(td);
```

Também podes juntar esse código em string, eu não gosto mas se quiseres poderia ser algo como:

```
var table = ...
var img = '<img src="img/edit.png" class="btn-action">';
[value.codigo, value.codigo, null].forEach(function(thing, i, arr){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = i == (arr.length - 1) ? img : thing;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
});
```